# Powershell script run by release agent throws exception because missing .net standard 2.0

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I try to run the script

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "myserver"  -Database "mydd"  -BackupFile "\\mypath.bak"
```

This works when I log into the release target and execute the script interactively.

If I turn it into a PowerShell task in a release pipeline I get the exception

> Could not load file or assembly  "netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" or one of its
>   dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
>
> In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18221\SqlServer.psm1:61
>   Zeichen:25
>   + ...       $binaryModule = Import-Module -Name $binaryModulePath -PassThru
>   +                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :   System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
>   Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the
>   error stream.

I also run the PowerShell console as the user that the release agents runs as and it worked. How can I further debug this issue?

I have on premise release agents and build agents.

Comment: Are you using a private agent installed on the release target?  What is the version of your  Powershell task?

Comment: Yes this runs on a self hosted agent

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I just got out of other threads. Please check if my answer give any helps.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I also run the PowerShell console as the user that the release agents runs as and it worked. How can I further debug this issue?

According to the troubleshooting you did, it seems that the difference between `powershell` task and private agent powershell is causing this issue.

When I use the powershell task, we could found it not use the powershell from the priavte agent:

[image]

As workaround, you could try to use the command line task invoke the powershell from the private agent, like:

```
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\Test.ps1
```

Hope this helps.